# multiprocessing error 'I/O operation on closed file'

Tags: python, file-io, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm having a problem with the Python multiprocessing package.

I'm using this method to run the code and use the multiprocessing module:

```
    import multiprocessing
    from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

    def change_file(simulation):
        for line in fileinput.FileInput(directory + '/file.txt', inplace=1):        
            for item in range(1,num_variables+1):
                line = line.replace('some text','other text')
            print (line.rstrip('\n'))

   pool = ThreadPool(2) 
   results = pool.map(change_file, Lists_of_works)
   pool.close() 
   pool.join()
```

This code it’s a component of a parametric program, and the program creates folders to identify simulations. Then inside each folder replace some text (different depending of each case) of a .txt file. The ‘directory’ name and the replaced text depend on the simulations. To perform the simulations I use multithreading. And this is the only component of the code that needs to use 1 core, because when I use 4, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I think the reason is because the main process open the file and the child close it…so the new main process use the same file. This reason it is explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899355/python-multiprocessing-valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-file)

SOLVED:
The solution is to store the text file on a global variable (string) and then replace the text as the post explains.

Thanks!

Comment: you use multiprocessing to edit the same file? why you need that :)

Comment: Please add clarification about what the following variables: num_variables, lists_of_works. 
Also, apart from just pasting code that does not work, you should clearly state what exactly you are trying to do in order for other people to help you.

Comment: SOLVED as it is explained in the post, with globals()